# Can't import legacy_seq2seq from tensorflow.contrib

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 0.12.1 on Python 3.5.2 on a Windows 10 64bit computer. For some reason, whenever I try to import `legacy_seq2seq` from `tensorflow.contrib`, it always occurs the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'legacy_seq2seq'`.

What causes the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example` - they've moved a lot of stuff from `tf.contrib` to main packages. This is because they updated their code, but not their examples - if you open github - you'll see a lot of requests to fix issues related to that!

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work for your version.

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.seq2seq import sequence_loss
```

In general, download the code for your tensorflow version from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases and then read the code to find out where your function is located.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem recently, and you should change from

```
from tensorflow.contrib import legacy_seq2seq
```

to

```
from tensorflow.contrib import seq2seq
```